# My KMM project won't run on an iPhone emulator

Tags: xcode, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a KMM project which runs perfectly on android, however when I open the project on Xcode for the IOS portion and try to run it on an emulator it does not compiler throwing the following error:

> BUILD FAILED in 3s
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

> What went wrong:
> Task 'embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode' not found in project ':shared'.

The app does run on my physical iPhone.

I have two questions:

1. How do I fix this?(if there is a fix)
2. Can I confidently work on my project without the emulator or should I take this error as a sign that there is something wrong with my project to the point of concern?

Kotlin Version: 1.5.31
Running on Mac with M1
using SQLDelight and Serialization dependencies.

Comment: The problem might be caused by the commented `iosSimulatorArm64` target inside of your shared/build.gradle.kts. This is an M1-specific target to build KMM artifacts for the simulator, and it's commented by default to avoid errors on Intel Macs.

Comment: I have the same issue and use an Intel mac.